# Input range value will count down but not up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***EDIT: solution found.  Adding necessary content for future users who come across this.

I'm completely stumped on why my JS can make this widget count down by single integers, but when it counts up its as if its concatenating "1" to the end of my box.

Maybe you can spot it in right away:

markup here:

```
<input type="text" name="volume" id="delta" class="change" value="50" />

<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step=".2" value="50" />
```

js here:

```
var timeout, tabMinus = $('#minus'), tabPlus = $('#plus');

//slider functionality
$('#slider').mouseup(function() {
    $('#delta').val($('#slider').val());
});

$('#delta').keyup(function() {
   $('#slider').val($('#delta').val());
});

//plus-minus tab functionality
tabMinus.mouseup(function() {
    $('#delta').val($('#slider').val() - 1);
    $('#slider').val($('#delta').val() - .2);
});

tabPlus.mouseup(function() {
    $('#delta').val($('#slider').val() + 1);
    $('#slider').val($('#delta').val() + .2);
    console.log($('#delta').val());
});
```

Also bonus points if there's a way to see LIVE updates as I drag the scroller, rather not rerender on the mouseup.

Here is fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jnurbina/rvf8j6te/1/

Comment: **All** of the content related to your question should be **in** your question, here on-site, not just linked. If you do link to an off-site resource, be sure to include all of the relevant content (including the HTML the code uses). But there's rarely any need to use jsFiddle here; instead, use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: I note that your slider is defined with `step="1"`, so I'm not sure what the goal of adding/subtracting `.2` is...

Comment: Yea my first time posting here not really sure of etiquette so just pasted the JS and decided if you wanted to see markup or styles you would click the fiddle nbd.  Anywho thanks for the help, steps were irrelevant prior; have them changed now to reflect decimal incre/decrements

Comment: Recommend putting the info in the question, even though it's been answered, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvf8j6te/2/)**

That because `.val()` return string you should parse it, use for example `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`:

```
//plus-minus tab functionality
tabMinus.mouseup(function() {
    $('#delta').val(parseInt($('#slider').val()) - 1);
    $('#slider').val(parseFloat($('#delta').val()) - .2);
});

tabPlus.mouseup(function() {
    $('#delta').val(parseInt($('#slider').val()) + 1);
    $('#slider').val(parseFloat($('#delta').val()) + .2);
});
```

The *reason* it would count down but not up is that the binary `-` operator is not overloaded, it always means subtraction. (There's a unary `-` operator, but the one that takes two operands — the binary one — is always subtraction). So the JavaScript engine coerces the values to numbers and performs subtraction. But the binary `+` operator is overloaded, it's defined for both strings (concatenation) and arithmetic (addition). When you give it strings, it does concatenation rather than addition, instead of coercing like `-` does.

Comment: Really @T.J.Crowder? 1.2 + .2 is not equal to 1.2. :) I thought my clue about being decimal values was enough to see the bug.

Comment: What about coercing the string, like `+$( '#slider' ).val()`, instead of `parseInt()`? In a more complex computation this might not be ideal, but for a simple one like above though, what do you think?

Comment: @epascarello: The version of the comment I saw didn't have that part. Obviously more clear now that it has it.

Comment: parseFloat is the key